# Using a heart curve equation as an area equation

Tags: integration, area, parametric

I am trying to find an equation for the area of a leaf for an ecology study. It’s a taro leaf, so it’s similar in shape to a heart curve I found, but I am stuck beyond that. I need to be able to plug in length and widths and return a value for the area. I’m attaching two pictures of the leaf, one real and one sketch. I’m also attaching a pic of the heart curve equation I found, but you’ll see it’s not quite the right shape. Can anyone please write an equation for “Area of a taro plant leaf” using this information? (And explain how you did it) Thank you!

*I cannot post images, so here’s the link to the problem written out with the pics:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU7X4VllGuXUZvcanqqtrF2IBdylDsNF/view?usp=drivesdk